# Can we extend Spring source code when working for a commercial app?

Tags: spring, open-source, licensing

I always have used Spring Framework classes as-is.

However I am thinking of customizing the Spring-WS (WebService) behavior by extending its WebServiceTemplate class.

The WebServiceTemplate currently offers only 'sendAndReceive', but I want to make it do only a 'send'. And then a separate thread do  a 'receive'.  (This is being done to mirror existing work flow that relies on Messaging).

So I was thinking of extending the class..

What sort of things do I need to be aware of, before extending from an Open Source code, for a commercial app? Also, Am I free to use the source code and copy it as need be?

UPDATE:
Looks like Spring uses same license as Apache

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring-WS use [Apache License](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/license.html). You are free to modify and use in commercial project. There are some restrictions (e.g., you can't use the Spring trademark), but this should be ok for most projects.

Comment: So, in my new java source code file, do I need to copy paste anything about licensing/copyright from the original Spring-WS class?

Comment: afaik, you need a notice, in source code and your license doc, saying this contain works from spring source, etc... But you don't have to distribute the source, so this is just some paperwork.

Comment: Also take care that this license normally does not cover the dependencies. *"Typically the licenses listed for the project are that of the project itself, and not of dependencies."*